# Every group of order 255 is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

There was previous task was same but with $N = 185$. And I prove it by showing that number of Sylow subgroups is 1 for every prime $p\mid N$. But there I have some options $N_5 \in \{1, 51\}$, $N_{17} = 1$, $N_3 \in \{1, 85\}$.

I've tried to get contradiction from $N_5 = 51$ or $N_3=85$, but I didn't manage to do it

I understand that it's impossible to have $N_5 = 51$ **and** $N_3=85$ at the same time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a finite group of order $|G| = 255 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17$. We will show that $G$ must be cyclic.

As you noticed, there must be only one Sylow subgroup $P$ of order $17$. Thus $P$ must be a normal subgroup. Since $17$ is prime the subgroup $P$ is cyclic, say $P = \langle a \rangle$. It is not difficult to see that every group of order $15$ is cyclic, so $G/P = \langle bP \rangle$ is also cyclic. Now $(bP)^{|b|} = P$, so $|bP| = 15 \mid |b|$.

If $|b| = 255$ we are done. Therefore we can assume $|b| = 15$. We will show that $ab = ba$ which implies that $ab$ has order $255$ since $15$ and $17$ are coprime. Because $P$ is normal, $bab^{-1} = a^i$ for some integer $i$. Using this fact we get $b^2ab^{-2} = ba^ib^{-1} = (bab^{-1})^i = a^{i^2}$ and by induction $b^kab^{-k} = a^{i^k}$ for all $k \geq 1$. Thus $a = b^{15}ab^{-15} = a^{i^{15}}$, which gives $i^{15} \equiv 1 \mod{17}$. By Fermat's little theorem $i^{16} \equiv 1 \mod{17}$ and since $15$ and $16$ are coprime, $i \equiv 1 \mod{17}$. Therefore $bab^{-1} = a$, proving the claim.

This exercise is a special case of a more general fact. Using the idea of this solution and the fact that in a group of squarefree order the Sylow subgroup corresponding to the largest prime is normal, you can prove that every group of order $n$ is cyclic when $n$ and $\varphi(n)$ are coprime ($\varphi$ is the totient function). This is done by Tibor Szele in the following short article (in German).

> T. Szele, *Über die endlichen Ordnungszahlen, zu denen nur eine Gruppe gehört*, Commentarii Mathematici Helvetici, 20, 265-67, (1947).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's solution I understand better.

Answer (score 29):

The key to $N=255$ is the observation that it is squarefree and coprime with its totient function.

Let $n_q$ denote the number of Sylow $q$-subgroups.

So, let us begin by the observation than any group $G$ of order $15$ is cyclic. Indeed, let us merely note $n_3\mid 5$, $n_3\equiv 1\text{ mod }3$ and so $n_3=1$. Similarly, $n_5\mid 3$ and $n_5\equiv 1\text{ mod }5$ which gives that $n_3=1$. Thus, we see that both the Sylow subgroups $P,Q$ of $G$ are both normal. Since evidently $P\cap Q=\{e\}$, and $PQ=G$ (since $\displaystyle |PQ|=\frac{|P||Q|}{|P\cap Q|}=\frac{15}{1}=15=|G|$) we may conclude that $G\cong P\times Q\cong\mathbb{Z}/3\times\mathbb{Z}/5\cong\mathbb{Z}/15$.

Now, to the case of $|G|=255$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $17$-subgroup. Note then that $n_{17}\mid 15$ and $n_{17}\cong 1\text{ mod }17$ gives $n_{17}=1$. Thus, we see that $P\unlhd G$. Now, here comes the step that is different than the standard approach. Since $P$ is normal we have that $G$ acts on $P$ by conjugation, giving us a group map $G\to\text{Aut}(P)$ whose kernel is $C_G(P)$. Now, note that since $P$ is just $C_{17}$ we have that $|\text{Aut}(P)|=16$. Note now that since $(|G|,16)=1$ you can conclude from the first isomorphism theorem that the image of the group map $G\to\text{Aut}(P)$ is trivial, and so the kernel is everything. This says that $C_G(P)=G$, and so $P\subseteq Z(G)$. Note then that $G/P$ is a group of order $15$ which, by what we have said in the previous paragraph, is cyclic. Now, it is a common theorem that if you mod out a group by a subgroup of its center and you get something cyclic, your group must have been abelian the whole time. So, from all of this we can conclude that $G$ is abelian in which case, by any method that tickles your fancy, you get that $G$ must just be $\mathbb{Z}/255$.

While the above may be ad hoc, it was actually just a simple application of the following (EXTREMELY USEFUL!) theorems:

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group and $N\unlhd G$. Then, if $(|G|,|\text{Aut}(N)|)=1$ then $N\leqslant Z(G)$.

and

> **Theorem:** If $G$ is a group and $N\leqslant Z(G)$ such that $G/N$ is cyclic of finite order, then $G$ is abelian.

These allow us to prove the more general theorem:

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group such that $(|G|,\varphi(|G|))=1$ (where $\varphi$ is the totient function), then $G$ is cyclic.

As a side note, a cool fact is that the integer $n$ has the property that the ONLY subgroup of order $n$ is $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is equivalent to $(n,\varphi(n))=1$.

The proof of the above can be found on my blog [here](http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/a-classification-of-integers-n-for-which-the-only-groups-of-order-n-are-cyclic-pt-i/).

Answer (score 8):

$$|N|=255=3\cdot 5\cdot 17$$

By Sylow theorem, the $\,17-$Sylow sbgp. $\,P_{17}\,$ is normal in $\,N\,$, so taking any $\,5-$Sylow sbgp. $\,P_5\,$, we get a sbgp. $\,K:=P_5P_{17}\,$ of index $\,3\,$ in $\,N\,$, and since this last is the minimal prime dividing $\,|N|\,$ , we get that $\,K\triangleleft N\,$ .

It's easy to prove that any group of order $\,85\,$ is cyclic , and thus its automorphism group has order $\,\phi(5)\phi(17)=64\,$ , so the only homomorphism $\,C_3\to Aut(K)\,$ ( the first group is the cyclic one of order $\,3\,$) there is is the trivial one (why?), and since by the above it follows that $\,N\cong K\rtimes P_3\,$ (with, of course, $\,P_3\cong C_3\,$), we get this semidirect product is in fact a direct one of abelian groups and, thus, $\,N\,$ is abelian and, in fact, cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

By Sylow, the 17-Sylow subgroup $P_{17}$ is normal in $N$. The group $G/P_{17}$ is of order $255 / 17 = 3\cdot 5$. By $5 \not\equiv 1\bmod 3$ and the classification of $pq$-groups, $G/P_{17}$ is cyclic.

The cyclic group $G/P_{17}$ has a normal subgroup of index $5$. By the [corresponcence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem), also $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of index $5$ (with $P_{17} \subseteq N$). We have $\#N = 255/5 = 3\cdot 17$.
By $17\not\equiv 1\bmod 3$ and the classification of $pq$-groups, $N$ is cyclic. So $N$ has a unique $3$-Sylow subgroup $P_3$. Then $P_3$ is also a $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$. As all $3$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are conjugate and $N$ is normal in $G$, we get that all $3$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ are contained in $N$. So $P_3$ is also the unique $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and therefore, $P_3$ is normal in $G$.

In the same way, we show that there is also a unique (and hence normal) $5$-Sylow subgroup $P_5$ of $G$. Hence all Sylow subgroups $P_3$, $P_5$ and $P_{17}$ are normal in $G$ and cyclic (by their prime order).
We get that $$G \cong P_3 \times P_5 \times P_{17} \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$$
is commutative.

(The Chinese remainder theorem takes us one step further implying that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/255\mathbb{Z}$ is even cyclic.)

Comment: The correspondence theorem link is not working.

Comment: @Emptymind thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another solution, making use of the observation in the initial question that it's "impossible to have $N_5=51$ and $N_3=85$ at the same time." (As otherwise $G$ would contain $85\cdot 2 + 51 \cdot 4 = 374 > 255 = \#G$ elements of order $3$ or $5$.)

The observation implies that at least one of the groups $P_3$ and $P_5$ is normal in $G$ and hence $U = P_3 P_5$ is a subgroup of $G$. (For $p\in\{3,5,17\}$ let $P_p$ denote a $p$-Sylow subgroup.)
As $P_3$ and $P_5$ have trivial intersection, $\#U = 3\cdot 5 = 15$. By the classification of $pq$-groups and $5\not\equiv 1\bmod 3$, the group $U$ is cyclic.

Moreover, $U$ is a complement of the normal subgroup $P_{17}$ in $G$ (as $U\cap P_{17} = \{e\}$ and $\#U \cdot \#P_{17} = \#G$). So $G \cong P_{17} \rtimes_\phi U$ with a group homomorphism $\phi : U \to \operatorname{Aut}P_{17}$. We have that $\#\operatorname{im}\phi\mid\#\operatorname{Aut}P_{17} = \varphi(17) = 16$. By the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms, moreover $\#\operatorname{im}\phi \mid \#U =  17$, forcing $\#\operatorname{im}\phi = 1$. Hence the homomorphism $\phi$ is trivial and the semidirect product $G$ is indeed the direct product $G\cong P_{17} \times U$ of two abelian groups. Therefore $G$ is abelian (and then cyclic, by the Chinese remainder theorem).

Answer (score 1):

This [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4509204/61691) leads to still another solution, maybe the most elementary one. Again we make direct use of the observation in the initial question that it's "impossible to have $N_5=51$ and $N_3=85$ at the same time." (As otherwise $G$ would contain $85⋅2+51⋅4=374>255=\#G$ elements of order $3$ or $5$.)

By $N_{17} = 1$, the $17$-Sylow group $P_{17}$ is normal in $G$. By the above observation, there is a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ of order $3$ or $5$. By the classification of $pq$-groups, the groups $G/P_{17}$ of order $15 = 3\cdot 5$ and $G/N$ of order $65 = 5\cdot 17$ or $51 = 3\cdot 17$ are both cyclic.

Consider the group homomorphism
$$\phi : G \to G/P_{17} \times G/N, \quad g\mapsto (gP_{17},gN).$$
Then $\ker\phi = P_{17} \cap N = \{e\}$, so $\phi$ is an injection and $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the abelian group $G/P_{17} \times G/N$ (abelian as a direct product of cyclic groups). Hence $G$ is abelian.

Comment: what is the classification of $pq$-groups?

Comment: Can not see exactly how did you use the statement in the link "recent question", could you clarify more please?

Comment: @Emptymind Classification Theorem: Let $p < q$ be two primes and $G$ a group of order $\#G = pq$. If $q \not\equiv 1 \bmod p$, then $G$ is cyclic. If $q \equiv 1\bmod p$, then $G$ is either cyclic or it is isomorphic to the single non-abelian semidirect product of the form $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Emptymind The statement in the linked question has been applied with the same $G$ and $N$ and with $M \leftarrow P_{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

Either $P_3$ or $P_5$ is normal, and hence central (think of the conjugacy classes of $G$). Accordingly, either $G/P_3$ or $G/P_5$ is cyclic (because both $5$ and $3$ do not divide $17-1=16$). So, $G$ is abelian (and hence cyclic).