# Group of order $105$ with a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $105 = 3 \times 5 \times 7$ with a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup, prove that $G$ is cyclic.

**My attempt**

I've been able to show that $G = NP$, where $N$ is the normal Sylow $3$-subgroup (which is of course cyclic) and $P$ is a cyclic group of order $35$. What's left to be shown is that $NP$ is cyclic. And I'm stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppose $|G| = 105$. Show that it is abelian if it has a normal $3$-Sylow subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257016/suppose-g-105-show-that-it-is-abelian-if-it-has-a-normal-3-sylow-subgro), since any finite abelian group of square-free order is cyclic.