# Finding a subgroup in the Center with order 91

Tags: abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

**Question:**

Let G be a group of order $455=5\cdot 7\cdot 13$.

- Show that exists a normal subgroup $ H<G: |H|=91$ and $H\subseteq Z(G)$.
- Show that G is an Abelian and cyclic group.

**Solution:**

So I showed that exists a normal subgroup by using Sylow's 3rd theorem to show that exists only one subgroup of order 7 $H_7$ (which is normal) and only one subgroup of order 13, $H_{13}$ (which is normal as well according to Sylow's 3rd). Then, I showed that $H_7 \cap H_{13}={e}$, such that $H_7\cdot H_{13}$ is a normal subgroup of order $7\cdot 13=91$.

From here, I didn't really know how to show that $H_7\cdot H_{13}$ is in the Center and that G is Abelian and cyclic.

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: Hint: see here <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255441/how-can-i-prove-that-every-group-of-n-255-elements-is-commutative/255474#255474>. Try to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

For a 4th solution:

How many Sylow 5 subgroups does $G/H_7$ have?

How many Sylow 5 subgroups does $G/H_{13}$ have?

Every subgroup of a quotient $G/H_i$ is of the form $K_i/H_i$ for some subgroup $K_i$ of $G$. How big is $K_7 \cap K_{13}$?

Is it normal?

This exercise is constructed in a silly way. Neither 7 nor 13 is equivalent to 1 mod 5, so of course the Sylow 5-subgroups are normal, by Hall (1928). However most students are not taught Hall's results, and so that they have to reprove them in smaller situations like this.

- Hall, P.
  “A note on soluble groups.”
  Journal of the London Mathematical Society **3**, (1928) 98-105.
  JFM [54.0145.01](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:54.0145.01)
  DOI:[10.1112/jlms/s1-3.2.98](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s1-3.2.98)

Comment: thanks a lot, but I cannot see the Journal, without registering for the site

Comment: The deeper knowledge may remain hidden until you visit the library. The hints I gave do not require these secrets, only the textbook Sylow and isomorphism theorems.

Comment: $+1^{\infty}$ I always enjoy reading your neat answers which are based on old documents and books. This is the right way of teaching abstract concepts. When I had a course about infinite abelian groups, you answered some of my questions. Thanks. Just saying thank you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You also could try the following: put $\,P_r\,$ for a Sylow $\,r$-subgroup, then:

A group $\,G\,$ of order $\;455=5\cdot 7\cdot 13\;$ has one unique Sylow $\,13$-subgroup, from which it follows that

$$P_{13}\lhd G\implies N:=P_{13}P_7\le G\;$$

and since $\,[G:N]=5=\,$ the minimal prime dividing $\,|G|\,$ , we get that in fact $\,N\lhd G\,$ , so that our group is an extension of  $\,N\,$ by a (any) Sylow $\,5$-subgroup $\,P_5\,$. But

$$\text{Aut}(N)\cong C_6\times C_{12}\implies|\text{Aut}(N)|=72$$

and since $5\nmid 72\,$ , the only possible homomorphism $\,P_5\to\text{Aut}(N)\,$ is the trivial one, from where the corresponding semidirect product is in fact direct:

$$N\rtimes P_5=N\times P_5$$

and since $\,N\,$ is abelian (and in fact cyclic: why?) and since also $\,P_5\;$ is,  we're done.

Comment: Why is $Aut(N)\cong C_6 \times C_12$? and what does $C_i$ mean?

Comment: $\;C_n=$ the (multiplicative, usually) cyclic group of order $\;n\;$. In general, the automorphism group of a direct product of cyclic groups is the direct product of the automorphisms groups.