# Groups order 957 are cyclics

Tags: cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Let G be an order 957 group. I have to prove that it is cyclic.

When I calculate Sylow p-subgroups for p=3, I find that 319 is a valid number or Sylow 3-subgroups. p=11 and p=29 gives me a normal Sylow p-subgroup for each of them.

I know that, if all Sylow groups were normal, we could probe the isomorfism to cyclic 957 group. By Sylow, how could this be solved?

Comment: But there isn't normal subgroups order 3, so I don't know how to prove that it's cyclic.

Comment: So with Euler's function it could be proved?

Comment: Yes, we have $\phi(957)=560$, which is coprime to $957$. So we are done. This uses the Sylow theorems, of course, see [here](https://yiminge.wordpress.com/2009/01/22/all-groups-of-order-n-are-cyclic-iff/).

Comment: Oh I'll check the proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick look [here](http://www.martin-flatin.org/math/euler_totient/1000.xhtml) tells us that $957$ is coprime to $\phi(957)$, where $\phi$ is the totient function. So we can use the strategy discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255441/how-can-i-prove-that-every-group-of-n-255-elements-is-commutative).